# OpenCL: What if i have more tasks then available work items?

Tags: multithreading, opencl, addition, workitem, workgroup

Let's make an example:

i want vector dot product made concurrently (it's not my case, this is only an example) so i have 2 large input vectors and a large output vector with the same size. the work items aviable are less then the sizes of these vectors. How can i make this dot product in opencl if the work items are less then the size of the vectors? Is this possible? Or i have just to make some tricks?

Something like:

```
for(i = 0; i < n; i++){  
    output[i] = input1[i]*input2[i];
}
```

with n > available work items

Comment: Note that your example is not the dot product, it's element-wise multiplication. Very wide dot product like that would require a reduction stage, which I think is not what you're asking.

Comment: yes sorry i mean element wise multiplication

Answer (score 1):

If by "available work items" you mean you're running into the maximum given by `CL_DEVICE_MAX_WORK_ITEM_SIZES`, you can always enqueue your kernel multiple times for different ranges of the array.

Depending on your actual workload, it may be more sensible to make each work item perform more work though. In the simplest case, you can use the SIMD types such as `float4`, `float8`, `float16`, etc. and operate on large chunks like that in one go. As always though, there is no replacement for trying different approaches and measuring the performance of each.

Comment: yes i mean maximum work items, but if i need that each work item must compute the element wise multiplication and n > work items how the gpu responds? it can be done or not? i know that each work item could compute much computation than a single one, but in the example how the gpu works? if works

Answer (score 0):

Divide and conquer data. If you keep workgroup size as an integer divident of global work size, then you can have N workgroup launches perhaps k of them at once per kernel launch. So you should just launch N/k kernels each with k*workgroup_size workitems and proper addressing of buffers inside kernels.

When you have per-workgroup partial sums of partial dot products(with multiple in-group reduction steps), you can simply sum them on CPU or on whichever device that data is going to.